# Configurable Product - Associated Products not saving

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Online 1.4.0.1 store has been up and running fine for 2 years. No changes made to site in months. Everything has always worked fine.

Yesterday, we added new Attribute, Attribute Set and Simple products. When we created a new Configurable Product (as we always have) the Associated Products appear fine but once we Select All and click Save and Continue Edit button it shows “Product was successfully saved” but Associated Products are not there. If we click Reset Filter button Assoc. Products reappear but Selecting All and trying again fails.

Also if we click Create Empty, Quick Create or Copy from Configurable buttons nothing happens.

Any solution, help or direction would be extremely appreciated. We’re stuck and can’t move forward with new products. Let us know if you need additional info or screen caps.

Please help if you can.

Comment: anything in the var/log/exception.log or var/log/system.log?